# Cyberduck Client & S3: signature calculated does not match the signature provided

Tags: amazon-s3, cyberduck

Situation:

S3 Bucket named BucketDataDeliveries

IAM User: the_deliverer

Tool: Cyberduck

I created a new user named the_deliverer. I am trying to connect to the bucket using cyberduck client but when start the connection appears the message:

The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Connection screenshot

[image]

*Policy*

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "BucketOperations",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::BucketDataDeliveries",
            "arn:aws:s3:::BucketDataDeliveries/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "ObjectOperations",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
            "s3:DeleteObject*",
            "s3:GetObject*",
            "s3:PutObject*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::BucketDataDeliveries",
            "arn:aws:s3:::BucketDataDeliveries/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "DenyAllOthers",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "NotResource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::BucketDataDeliveries",
            "arn:aws:s3:::BucketDataDeliveries/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

when you want to access to the bucket using owner account the url to define in cyberduck s3 connection is:
bucket.s3.amazonaws.com

But when you want to access with other user created in IAM the url of the server is:
bucket.s3-zone.amazonaws.com

In my example:
BucketDataDeliveries.s3-us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com